# overflow: hidden; on transitioning element

Tags: overflow, css-transitions, css

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3BN/) (fiddle), `a` is the parent and is set to `overflow: hidden;`. `span` is the child and has `box-shadow` set. When nothing happens, everything goes well, but when a user hovers the `a`, its `overflow` property seems to get overwritten (i.e. the shadow is shown in a square, rather than a circle, as it should). Any idea how to solve this?

Code:
**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Hover me"><span>Hover me</span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    background: red;

    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;

    border-radius: 200px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -8px;
}

a > span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -35px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

a:hover > span {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -28px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not understable but try this if it can help you then....

```
a {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    background: red;

    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;

    border-radius: 200px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

a:hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
}

a > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -35px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

a:hover > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -28px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Comment: I think my question is understandable, and no, your answer doesn't help.